# Drawing vertical text on iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I'd like to draw an `NSAttributedString` (or `NSString`) vertically on iOS. By "vertically" I mean:

[image: Vertical text example]

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) says a standard attribute on an `NSAttributedString` is `NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName`, but unfortunately, says:

> "In iOS, horizontal text is always used and specifying a different value is undefined."

[The same document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) also mentions `NSTextLayoutSectionsAttribute`, which seems to support `NSTextLayoutOrientation`, which allows `NSTextLayoutOrientationHorizontal` or `NSTextLayoutOrientationVertical`.

None of those 4 terms get **any** hits on SO at the moment. *Just that lonely whistling sound*.

However, I don't have any idea how to set this up, whether it works with iOS, or if can be used for vertical string rendering in the style of `[myAttributedString drawAtPoint: whereItOughtaGo]`.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to draw or use default `UILabel`? It could be possible with `UILabel`..

Comment: did you tried characterwarp

Comment: @iMani I would prefer to draw, but I might be able to use `UILabel`.

Comment: @iDev Thanks for the idea. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode) the `NSString` drawing methods supporting `lineBreakMode:` and able to take `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` are deprecated in iOS 7. Is that what you meant? Isn't there also a difficulty with setting the draw rect to the right size to ensure that every character fits in, but every character gets wrapped to its own line? If you could expand on the idea, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: I played around with `NSTextLayoutSectionsAttribute` and even subclassed `NSTextContainer` to override `layoutOrientation` to return `NSTextLayoutOrientationVertical`. It doesn't work. I see the typesetter querying for layout orientation, but rendering is still done in horizontal orientation. I guess it's a Core Text limitation.

Comment: Hi @LeoNatan thank you very much for looking at that option – I didn't see where to begin with it. I don't know wether SO has a guideline on negative answers? As in, "you can't do it with the options the O.P. suggested as of iOS 7. Consider a work around such as those in the other answers." I'd vote that up as a useful answer anyway!

Comment: @Benjohn There is no such rule, no.

Comment: @LeoNatan I'll add that as a simple answer, unless you'd prefer to?

Comment: @Benjohn Why not, added an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it just a single lined text as in your example you can use various workarounds. I would personally create a `UILabel` subclass as follows:

```
@implementation VerticalLabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

  if (self) {
    self.numberOfLines = 0;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
  NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];

  for (int i = text.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c\n", [text characterAtIndex:i]];
  }

  super.text = newString;
}

@end
```

Now you just have to replace:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

with:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[VerticalLabel alloc] init];
```

to get vertical text.

Comment: *nods* Nice work around, thanks for that. If I'm just wanting to rendering the text down in to a bitmap, this should also work nicely, I think.

Comment: Done. I'll leave the question open for a while before I accept your answer in case anyone can shed light on the `NSTextLayoutSectionsAttribute` I mentioned.

Comment: @Benjohn Make sure to center the text alignment so that letters are correctly aligned (in your example - 'i' in the middle of 'L', etc.).

Answer (score 6):

You can draw your vertical text by using CoreText (to get glyphs) and CoreGraphics (to draw CGGlyphs).
A simple sample, that's only take care of one font attribute (handle the effective range for each attribute, if want to handle different font, font size, etc …)

```
#import "NSAttributedString+VerticalDrawing.h"

@implementation TestView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is a vertical text"
                                                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.]}];
    [aString drawVerticalAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
}
@end

@implementation NSAttributedString (VerticalDrawing)

- (void)drawVerticalAtPoint:(CGPoint)location
{
    UIFont *font = [[self attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL] objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSUInteger myLength = [self length];

    CTFontRef ctfont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)[font fontName], [font pointSize], NULL);

    CGGlyph *glyphs = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * myLength);
    UniChar *characters = malloc(sizeof(UniChar) * myLength);
    CGSize *advances = malloc(sizeof(CGSize) * myLength);

    [[self string] getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0,myLength)];

    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctfont, characters, glyphs, myLength);
    CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(ctfont, kCTFontHorizontalOrientation, glyphs, advances, myLength);

    free(characters);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFontRef cgfont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont(ctfont, NULL);

    CGContextSetFont(ctx, cgfont);
    CGContextSetFontSize(ctx, CTFontGetSize(ctfont));

    CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(location.x, location.y);
    textMatrix = CGAffineTransformScale(textMatrix, 1, -1);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, textMatrix);

    CGFloat lineHeight = CTFontGetAscent(ctfont) + CTFontGetDescent(ctfont) + CTFontGetLeading(ctfont);
    location.y = -CTFontGetAscent(ctfont);

    CGFloat maxAdvance = 0.;

     NSUInteger i;
     for (i = 0; i < myLength; i++)
         maxAdvance = MAX(maxAdvance, advances[i].width);

    for (i = 0; i < myLength; i++)
    {
        location.x = (maxAdvance - advances[i].width) * 0.5;

        CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(ctx, &glyphs[i], &location, 1);
        location.y -= lineHeight;
    }

    free(glyphs);
    free(advances);
    CGFontRelease(cgfont);
    CFRelease(ctfont);
}
@end
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Emmanuel, I'd not considered going that low level, but it looks achievable, so I'll reconsider if I need to. Whether or not I use it, thanks for a detailed look at how the underlying mechanics work.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other great answers, I played around with `NSTextLayoutSectionsAttribute` and even subclassed `NSTextContainer` to override `layoutOrientation` to return `NSTextLayoutOrientationVertical`. It doesn't work. I see `NSATSTypesetter` querying for layout orientation, but rendering is still done in horizontal orientation. I guess it's a Core Text limitation; documentation and header files state numerous times that only horizontal layout orientation is supported in Core Text.

As per documentation, the `NSTextLayoutOrientationProvider` protocol is only provided if a subclass of `NSLayoutManager` wishes to implement a different layout orientation.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw it with attribute you can create a paragraph attribute and set the left and right margins for 0 or very small. This results in a vertical display string when drawAtPoint is used.